# unshare a new PID namespace and start shell from background "unshare --fork --pid /bin/bash &" , the login session terminate

Tags: bash, shell, namespaces, unshare

I'm working on test. When I try to start a PID namespace and set it to background, it looks work and I get the prompt.
But if I try to run any else, whenever I type the first character, the session just close.
This is also the same if I change bash to sh.

```
    [root@opensshtest ~]# unshare --fork --pid /bin/bash &
    [1] 10136
    [root@opensshtest ~]# [root@opensshtest ~]# elogout
    Connection to opensshtest.cn.ibm.com closed.
```

But for other type namespace, it works fine. Like

```
    [root@opensshtest ~]# unshare --fork --uts /bin/bash &
    [1] 10372
    [root@opensshtest ~]# jobs
    [1]+  Stopped                 unshare --fork --uts /bin/bash
    [root@opensshtest ~]#
```

Is this operation limited for PID namespace and not supported?
Any document define this?

Comment: I can reproduce it. The parent shell's `read` from STDIN returns EIO (Input/output error) - but why?